Closed form for the A357990 using A329369 and generalised A373183

Let

$$
\ell(n) = \left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor, \\
\ell(0) = -1
$$

Let

$$
f(n) = \ell(n) - \ell(n-2^{\ell(n)}) - 1
$$
Here $f(n)$ is A290255.

Let $A(n,k)$ be a square array such that

$$
A(n,k) = A(n-2^{\ell(n)}, k+1)(k+1)^{f(n)+1} - A(n-2^{\ell(n)}, k)k^{f(n)+1}, \\
A(0,k) = 1
$$
Here $A(n, k)$ is A357990. In particular, $A(n, 1)$ is A329369.

Let $R(n, m, x)$ be the family of polynomials such that

$$
R(2n+1, m, x) = xR(n, m, x), \\
R(2n, m, x) = x(R(n, m, x+1) - R(n, m, x)), \\
R(0, m, x) = \prod\limits_{i=0}^{m-1} (x+i)
$$
In particular, $R(n, 1, x)$ is associated with A373183.
I conjecture that for $0\leqslant q<2^m$
$$
\frac{1}{p!}\sum\limits_{i} A(2^m(2^{i-1}-1)+q, 1)[x^i]R(n, p, x) = A(2^m n + q, p)
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:
A(n, k) = my(A = 2*n+1, B, C, v1, v2); v1 = []; while(A > 0, B=valuation(A, 2); v1=concat(v1, B+1); A \= 2^(B+1)); v1 = Vecrev(v1); A = #v1; v2 = vector(A, i, 1);  for(i=1, A-1, B = A-i; for(j=1, B, C = B-j+k+1; v2[j] = v2[j]*C^v1[B] - v2[j+1]*(C-1)^v1[B])); v2[1]
R(n, m) = my(x = 'x, A = prod(i=0, m-1, x+i)); forstep(i=if(n == 0, -1, logint(n, 2)), 0, -1, A = if(bittest(n, i), x*A, x*(subst(A, x, x+1) - A))); A
test(n, m, p, q) = my(v1); v1 = Vecrev(R(n, p)/x); 1/p!*sum(i=1, #v1, A(2^m*(2^(i-1) - 1) + q, 1)*v1[i]) == A(2^m*n + q, p)

Is there a way to prove it?

It seems correct. See the Mathematica code as supplement to the PARI/GP code
